# Customize content page in backend with more filters

Tags: views

I need to add more filters like content type, Taxonomy to back end content() in drupal. Hacking the core is not a good method. Is there any alter hooks are available?. Can create a new view page with exposed filters and do a views bulk operation on it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for it! :)
You should take a look at [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views). This module gives you all you need. Just create views for nodes or users or use the default ones that come with the module. It has a dependency to Views Bulk Operations as it can perform customizable tasks, like mass deleting or changing values.